# ASP.NET Time Drop Downs and AM/PM Issue

Tags: asp.net, datetime, usability

I've searched already for some ideas on this but the answers were totally code-based; my problem is also a HCI/Usability issue:

[https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[asp.net]+time+am+pm](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp.net%5D%20time%20am%20pm)

I have an events form with a calendar. Then I have three drop down lists for Hours, Mins and AM/PM. But technically, 12 Noon and 12 Midnight are not AM or PM, correct?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight

I have thought about adding "Noon" and "Midnight" to the AM/PM drop down but I would be assuming that the user would know the correct usage (they won't). I could create the AM/PM as a cascading drop down based on the hour selected?

There are probably many ways to hack this up - but I'm looking for suggestions that take usability into account - simple and elegant solution anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution would be not to use an ambiguous system, use the 24-hour clock instead and the problem goes away.

Comment: And that's more of a problem than your"noon or midnight" issue?  I think the issue of people not understanding the 24 hour clock is a lot smaller than you think.  So far I haven't had one complaint for sites using the 24 hour clock which are exposed to more than 100,000 users a day.

Comment: Agreed, but this is for an internal admin which will be used by barely literate people, some of whom don't even speak English; they're mainly Latino and I'm trying to find the simplest possible way of presenting this... do you think 24 hr clock is the best option in this scenario?

Comment: I do, particularly if it's a closed group of people who can have some training - perhaps a tooltip which explains the concept of the 24 hour clock in their native language, with a few common examples of converting between.

Answer (score 0):

In modern western society 12:00am refers to midnight and 12pm to noon. the simple solution we normally employ is to avoid any form of confusion and use a 24:00 based time instead. It also results in one less drop down to select from in this case.